# Find usage of id not working in Android Studio on Windows

Tags: java, android, android-studio, utility

I selected an id in XML, mouse right click, find Usage shows no occurrence of id even Id exist in java file. And if i do the same in Mac its finding it.

So is there any cache issue or something else ?

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: No luck even auto complete is also not working :-(

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To fix the autocomplete go to:

File -> Invalidate Caches -> Restart -> Click at Invalidate and Restart

Comment: This answer is not related to the question although its useful in the answer context itself. Finding usage is not working even when Invalidate Cashes and Restart. There is still an issue with it

Comment: This also fixed Ctrl+Shift+F shortcut key to "Find in Path" stop working after Android Studio updated.

Comment: I have to do this everytime I use find usages, what a joke, slows down coding about 1000x

Answer (score 8):

Another reason why that shortcut is not working is that, probably you GEFORCE EXPERIENCE is using that shortcut, which happened to my system:
Remove that shortcut in your GEFORCE EXPERIENCE

[image]

I learned that from the following link:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206845105/comments/115000444830

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was not finding anything since I had **"File name Filter"** checked and I was just looking in build.gradle.

[image]

There are two options to resolve the problem:

```
1. Uncheck option "File name Filter" or,
2. Just filter to *.java or whatever type of file you want
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and unfortunately **@josedlujan's** answer does not solve the problem.

Alternatively, you my try the **`Ctrl`**+**`Shift`**+**`F`** to certainly find what you want, also **double** clicking **`Shift`** will open a quick dialog to find certain keyword in the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may have problems with "Auto-Complete" and "Find" functionality in IntelliJ-based IDEs:

Did you check whether the project's directories with source codes are excluded from indexing? If they are excluded, the IntelliJ-based IDEs do not index those directories' contents. As you know, you can check this by right click on your desired directories, then **->** **Mark Directory as -> Not Excluded**.

I hope it will be helpful.